# Meaning of 3D when used BEFORE a url not within one

Tags: html, 3d

I have this piece of html from wikipedia.

```
<a href=3D"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judith_Ehrlich" title=3D"Judith Ehrlich">Judith Ehrlich</a>
```

I understand "=3D" is Quoted-Printable encoding for "=" but im not sure what 3D"URL" means.  Normally when I would see a link in HTML it would be written like this

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judith_Ehrlich" title="Judith Ehrlich">Judith Ehrlich</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In quoted-printable, any non-standard octets are represented as an `=` sign followed by two hex digits representing the octet's value. To represent a plain `=`, it needs to be represented using quoted-printable encoding too: `3D` are the hex digits corresponding to `=`'s ASCII value (61).

In other words, the sequence of `=3D"URL"` in those fields is converted to just `="URL"`. `3D"URL"` without `=` has no meaning on its own.

If used in a parsing/rendering situation that is interpreting `=` as a QP encoding, omitting `3D` would result in the parser wrongly interpreting the next characters (e.g. "U) as a byte encoding. Using `=3D` would be necessary to insert an actual `=` in the parsed result.

Comment: Can think of a reason why this technique would be used to represent a character that is normally used without this particular encoding?

Comment: If used in a parsing/rendering situation that is interpreting `=` as a QP encoding, omitting `3D` would result in the parser wrongly interpreting the next characters (e.g. `"U`) as a byte encoding. Using `=3D` would be necessary to insert an actual `=` in the parsed result.

Comment: The question Scott has asked is better way of indicating the question that I had.